# Discover the class of a methodinvocation in the Annotation Processor for java

Tags: java, annotations, preprocessor, javac

I am writing some tools for our build system to enforce some strict calling conventions on methods belonging to classes containing certain annotations.

I'm using the Compiler Tree API...

What i'm wondering is when traversing the 'tree', how can you tell the type of class/interface for a MethodInvocation.

I'm subclassing TreePathScanner with :

```
@Override
public Object visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocationTree node, Trees trees) {

}
```

I'm hoping theres a way to tell the type of the class(or interface) that you're trying to invoke the method on.  Am I going about this the wrong way?  Thanks for any ideas...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.  You can either be interested in
knowing the Java type of the method invocation receiver or just
knowing the class on the method is invoked.  Java information is more
informative as it gives you generic types as well, e.g. `List<String>`
while Elements would only provide you with the class, e.g. `List<E>`.

**Getting the Element**

To get the Element of the class the method is invoked on, you can do
the following:

```
  MethodInvocationTree node = ...;
  Element method =
        TreeInfo.symbol((JCTree)node.getMethodSelect());
  TypeElement invokedClass = (TypeElement)method.getEnclosingElement();
```

Corner cases:

1.
invokedClass might be a superclass of the receiver type.  So running
the snippet on `new ArrayList<String>.equals(null)` would return
`AbstractList` rather than `ArrayList`, since equals() is implemented
in `AbstractList` not `ArrayList`.

2.
When handling array invocations, e.g. `new int[].clone()`, you would
get `TypeElement` of class `Array`.

**Getting the actual type**

To get the type, there is no direct way for determining it what the
receiver type is.  There is some complexity in handling method invocations
within inner classes where the receiver is not given explicitly
(e.g. unlike `OuterClass.this.toString()`).  Here is a sample implementation:

```
  MethodInvocationTree node = ...;
  TypeMirror receiver;
  if (methodSel.getKind() == Tree.Kind.MEMBER_SELECT) {
    ExpressionTree receiver = ((MemberSelectTree)methodSel).getExpression();
    receiverType = ((JCTree)receiver).type;
  } else if (methodSel.getKind() == Tree.Kind.IDENTIFIER) {
    // need to resolve implicit this, which is described in
    //  JLS3 15.12.1 and 15.9.2

    // A bit too much work that I don't want to work on now
    // Look at source code of
    //   Attr.visitApply(JCMethodInvocation)
    //   resolveImplicitThis(DiagnosticPosition, Env, Type)
  } else
    throw new AssertionError("Unexpected type: " + methodSel.getKind());
```

Note:

The `receiver` type needs to be `TypeMirror` not `DeclaredType`
unfortunately.  When calling `new int[5].clone()`, `receiver` would be
an `ArrayType` of `int[]`, which is more informative than the previous
method.

**Getting it to run**

Both of the previous methods require the compiler to resolve the type
information for the classes.  In usual circumstances, the compiler
only resolve the types for method declarations but not the bodies.
Hence, the methods described earlier would return `null` instead.

To have the compiler resolve the type information, you can do one of
the following ways:

1.
Use `AbstractTypeProcessor` class that just got added to the
compiler repository for JDK 7.  Check out the work on [JSR
308](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/pag/jsr308/) and their compiler.
While the work is mainly on annotated types, it might be useful for.
The compiler allows you to use the provided class in a backward
compatible manner with Java 5.

This approach allows you to write processors that get invoked just
like your current processors.

2.
Use `JavacTask` instead and call `JavacTask.analyze()`.  Look at
the main method of [this javac test](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/langtools/file/6855e5aa3348/test/tools/javac/api/6557752/T6557752.java) to see how
to invoke your visitor on the classes.

This approach makes your processor look more like an analysis tool
rather than a plug-in to the compiler, as you would need to invoke it
directly rather than have it be a regular process.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  However, the line:

Element method =
        TreeInfo.symbol((JCTree)node.getMethodSelect());
returns null for me.  

     TypeMirror m = trees.getTypeMirror(path);
also returns null, as does
    
     TypeElement e = (TypeElement) trees.getElement(path);
Am I making a rookie mistake and forgetting to initialize something, or calling/overriding the wrong method, or subclassing something wrong?  Thanks again for your help...

Comment: I just updated the entry to explain why the methods return null and how to address that

Comment: FYI, AbstractTypeProcessor is no longer available in JDK 7 builds, since support for JSR 308 was dropped.