# Java8, how discover the class and method name in visitMethodInvocation?

Tags: java, annotations, javac

With Java7 and Java8, I would like to generate a warning if some methods was called.
The warning will be print if a specific jar is present when then user compile.

I write an Annotation Processor and catch the visitMethodInvocation(). Now, I want extract the class and method names will be invoked.

Is it possible to do that ?
Or how to approach this?

Comment: Did you checked the reflection APIs? I haven't used it but it seems a way to extract details at runtime. Please post your solution here whenever you solved it. I am eager to know :) :)

Comment: I would generate a warning at compile time. No at runtime.

Comment: This answer did not solve the problem?

[Discover the class of a methodinvocation in the Annotation Processor for java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066555/discover-the-class-of-a-methodinvocation-in-the-annotation-processor-for-java

Comment: The apt was removed in Java 8. I think you need to clarify further what exactly it is you want to achieve. If the question is "is a specific class present at build time", then you could easily write a test case to check for that, e.g. using `Class.forName`, failing if the class can be found.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like:

```
package mystuff;

import com.sun.source.tree.*;
import com.sun.source.util.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.element.*;
import javax.tools.*;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")
    public class Proc extends AbstractProcessor{
    @Override
        public boolean process(Set<?extends TypeElement>annotations,RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment){
        final Trees trees=Trees.instance(processingEnv);
        for(Element element:roundEnvironment.getRootElements()){
        TreePath path=trees.getPath(element);
        final CompilationUnitTree compilationUnit=path.getCompilationUnit();
        compilationUnit.accept(new TreeScanner<Object,Object>(){
            @Override
                public Object visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocationTree tree,Object data){
                tree.getMethodSelect().accept(new SimpleTreeVisitor<Object,Object>(){
                    @Override
                    public Object visitMemberSelect(MemberSelectTree tree,Object data){
                    processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE,String.format("class:  %1$s\nmethod: %2$s",tree.getExpression(),tree.getIdentifier()));
                    return null;
                    }
                },null);
                return null;
            }
            },null);
        }
        return true;
    }
    }
```

I used that processor to process the below class

```
package stuff;

import java.util.*;

@MyAnnotation
class MyProgram{
    public void run(){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

and achieved this result:

```
class:  System.out
  method: println
```

I am pretty sure that the method name generated is what you are looking for.  I am pretty sure that the "class" is not exactly what you are looking for, but is a pretty good start.

In my example you probably wanted it to print "java.io.PrintStream" for the class.  To get that you could use `processingEnv.getElementUtils().getTypeElement("java.lang.System")` to get a TypeElement representing the system class.  Then you can use `processingEnv.getElementUtils().getAllMembers()` to get every single member of the system class.  Iterate through that to find `out`.  Use the `asType` method to get its type.

The preceding paragraph was a gross simplification.  The processor did not know a priori that `out` is a static member of a class that is part of the implicitly imported `java.lang` package.  So your code will have to try and fail to find the following classes `System` and `java.util.System` (because it is in the imports), `System.out`, `java.util.System.out`, and `java.lang.System.out`.

I only dealt with MemberSelect.  You will have to deal with other possibilities including MethodInvocation.  For example `new Object().toString().hashCode()` should be class=Object, method=hashCode.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the great answer from @emory, you can consider using the pluggable type-checking annotation processing provided by [the Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/). The advantage is it can help you to easily determinate the type of the method invoker. Here is an example processor based on the checker framework (add checker.jar to the classpath when compile).

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class MyTypeProcessor extends AbstractTypeProcessor {
    class MyTreePathScanner extends TreePathScanner<Void, Void> {
        private final Trees trees;
        private final TreePath root;

        public MyTreePathScanner(TreePath root) {
            this.trees = Trees.instance(processingEnv);
            this.root = root;
        }

        @Override
        public Void visitMemberSelect(MemberSelectTree node, Void aVoid) {
            ExpressionTree expression = node.getExpression();
            TreePath expr = TreePath.getPath(root, expression);
            TypeMirror type = trees.getTypeMirror(expr);
            Element typeElement = processingEnv.getTypeUtils().asElement(type);
            Optional<? extends Element> invoker = typeElement.getEnclosedElements().stream().filter(
                    e -> e.getSimpleName().equals(node.getIdentifier())).findFirst();
            if (invoker.isPresent() && invoker.get().getKind() == ElementKind.METHOD) {
                System.out.println("Type: " + typeElement + ", method: " + invoker.get());
            }
            return super.visitMemberSelect(node, aVoid);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void typeProcess(TypeElement typeElement, TreePath root) {
        new MyTreePathScanner(root).scan(root, null);
    }
}
```

Which is processing the following input source.

```
public class Test {

    public void foo() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        Test t = new Test();
        t.foo();
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Type: java.io.PrintStream, method: println()
Type: Test, method: foo()
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this framework, but it looks like a better solution.

Comment: The framework is basically an extension to the Oracle javac which can be used for extra source code checking.